# "Permission denied" in Fedora Terminal for some directories

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, fedora

extremely new to linux here. I am in a class that often calls for using "grep" command in Fedora 20. However, when used in most directories, I am greeted with "Permission denied" I have spent hours searching the internet and have not found the solution. I am sure it is something basic.

Note that my account type is Administrator and using "sudo" does not grant me access to run grep.

The specific grep command I am running is "grep Wico /etc/shadow" Wico is my username on the VM.

Question #2 is. While in Ubuntu, in terminal, using the "shasum" command leaves a blank line on the next line in which I have to cancel out as its like stuck loading/frozen. Again, I am administrator and sudo does not resolve this. I have tried the other "shasum" interpretations like sha1sum, shasum256 or whatever that command is. None work.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, linux uses permission to determine if a user or a group can read write or execute a file/directory. `/etc/shadow` stores hashed passwords, as you may guess, normal users cannot read and modify this file. To read this file you need to execute a command as the super user (`sudo`) if you were to type `sudo grep Wico /etc/shadow` you would then see the line that contains your (hashed) password.

Q2:
shasum is a command that takes a file as the first parameter, if none is specified it will use stdin (your keyboard in this case) if you type stuff and then press `CRTL + D` (which inserts `EOF`) you would see the hash made from what you typed.

If you don't know how to use a command type `man [the command]` and the manual will explain how to use it.

Comment: I appreciate all the help, it makes sense now. After using the "Sudo" command beforehand I noticed that it is still blank. However, manually going to the destination folder and locating the file "shadow" when clicking it it states that the file is of an unknown type. I am guessing it is some sort of data file that is unreachable without terminal/sudo request. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @DustinWhen dealing with protected files you should use a terminal, and in linux most files are text. If you want to see the content of shadow you need to run sudo cat /etc/shadow. Don't take it the wrong way, but you should complete [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-basics) before continuing.